# Multiple loggings in the same line as well as in different lines in same file in java

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am new to using Log4j logger,I wanted to print some of the logging statements to 
be in the same line.

Example :

```
log.debug(root.data);
    if(root.left!=null)
        log.debug("("+root.left.data);
    else if(root.left==null)
        log.debug("null");
    if(root.right!=null)
        log(root.right.data+")");
    else if(root.right!=null)
        log.debug("null)");
```

It will print like this (3,

```
                null)
```

**But i wanted to print like this (3,null).**

But i have other log statements which should be printed in normal behaviour

Example:

```
void function()
{
log.debug("Entered First Function");
}
public static void Main()
{
log.debug("In Main Method");
}
```

In Main Method

Entered First Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) and a pair of [ternaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). Something like,

```
log.debug(String.format("(%s, %s)", //
        root.left == null ? "null" : root.left.data, //
        root.right == null ? "null" : root.right.data));
```

**or** without the ternaries like

```
if (root.right == null || root.left == null) {
    if (root.left == null) {
        if (root.right == null) {
            log.debug("(null, null)");
        } else {
            log.debug(String.format("(null, %s)", root.right.data);
        }
    } else {
        log.debug(String.format("(%s, null)", root.left.data);
    }
} else {
    log.debug(String.format("(%s, %s)", root.left.data, root.right.data);
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of how not to use ternaries. That code is not reasonable readable at first glance.

Comment: Code has been modified since my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Correct log4j idiom (1.2 version) would be

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
  log.debug("(" + root.left.data + "," + root.right.data + ")");
}
```

It will take care of the nulls correctly. The condition will prevent any performance hit in case debug level is disabled.

You might want to use some more modern logging api, like slf4j, logback or log4j 2. The readability would be much better:

```
log.debug("({},{})", root.left.data, root.right.data);
```